# interaction failed without any reason discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was making a simple coinflip command in my discord bot. It is working but makes an "Interaction Failed" event without reason. It edits the embed and changes things it should change. and it deletes the message without any problem.

My Code:

```js
const randomResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? "Heads" : "Tails";

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Coin Flip")
.setColor("YELLOW")
.setDescription(` > ${randomResult}`)
.setFooter({
text: `Requested by ${message.author.username}`,
iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
});

const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
new MessageButton()
.setCustomId("again")
.setLabel("Throw Again")
.setEmoji("")
.setStyle("PRIMARY"),

new MessageButton()
.setCustomId("delete")
.setLabel("Delete")
.setEmoji("♻")
.setStyle("DANGER")
);
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] }).then(msg => {
global.msg = msg;
})
const iFilter = (i) => i.user.id === message.author.id;
const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
filter: iFilter,
time: 30000,
});
collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
if (i.customId === "again") {
const randomResult =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? "Heads" : "Tails";
const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Coin Flip")
.setColor("YELLOW")
.setDescription(` > ${randomResult}`)
.setFooter({
text: `Requested by ${message.author.username}`,
iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
});
const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
new MessageButton()
.setCustomId("again")
.setLabel("Throw Again")
.setEmoji("")
.setStyle("PRIMARY"),
new MessageButton()
.setCustomId("delete")
.setLabel("Delete")
.setEmoji("♻")
.setStyle("DANGER")
);
msg.edit({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });
}
if (i.customId === "delete") {
msg.delete();
}
})
collector.on("end", async (i) => {
const newEmbed2 = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Coin Flip")
.setColor("YELLOW")
.setDescription(` > ${randomResult}`)
.setFooter({
text: `Requested by ${message.author.username}`,
iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
});
const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
new MessageButton()
.setCustomId("ended")
.setLabel("Coin Flip Ended")
.setEmoji("❎")
.setStyle("DANGER")
.setDisabled(true),
);
msg.edit({embed: [newEmbed2], components: [row]})
})
```

Note: I am not getting any errors. I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

Answer (score 0):

You still have to reply to the interaction using Interaction#reply() method. This is to acknowledge to discord that you handled the interaction. Something like `interaction.reply("success")` will probably do the job